# What documents does a Pakistani need when arriving in Seychelles?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, pakistani-citizens, visas-on-arrival, seychelles

I'm Pakistani, living in Pakistan. I can enter Seychelles visa-free, but need to know what documents I might need when I arrive at immigration there. Would I need a No Objection Certificate?

Comment: What is a NOC? Your question is very unclear, however in general you’ll need a valid passport or other travel documents recognized by Seychelles. The passport must be valid for the period of the intended stay until arrival back in the holder’s country of origin or residence.
A visitor’s permit is issued on arrival in Seychelles to those who meet the required criteria, including having a valid return or onward ticket for duration of the visit, confirmed accommodation; and sufficient funds for duration of the stay. http://www.mfa.gov.sc/static.php?content_id=1

Comment: @Traveller it is a [no objection certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Objection_Certificate).

Comment: I mean do I need no objection certificate for traveling to Seychelles

Comment: Who will issue such an NOC?  You can ask the airline when you go to buy tickets. I’m sure if you are visa free you do not need any such NOC.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TimaticWeb](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html), you would need only the following to enter Seychelles:

> Visa Issuance:
>
> - Passengers can obtain a "Visitor's Permit" on arrival for a
>     maximum stay of 30 days. They must have:
>
>   - a return/onward ticket; and
>   - sufficient funds (minimum of USD 150.- or equivalent per
>       day); and
>   - proof of accommodation for the duration of stay.

However, you would still need to check what your own country may require of its departing citizens and any visa(s) needed to transit or connect on your journey from Pakistan to Seychelles.